# Manage secrets in GitHub Actions

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I'm trying to find the way how to secretly deploy my Azure access keys to inject them into GitHub Actions.
The problem is that I have no access to the Settings of a GitHub repo, admin of the repo is slow - he will add a new GitHub secret in a week at best, but I need to test the GitHub workflow now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have collaborator access and a personal access token with the `repo` scope, you can [use the API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#create-or-update-a-repository-secret) to add secrets to the repository.  If you can't do that, then you'll just have to wait.  Alternatively, if you already have access to an alternative secret store via the GitHub Actions secrets, then you could use that.

Note that GitHub doesn't provide secret backdoors to the repository settings because the admin is slow.  That's an organizational problem.